# How to get the loss history using Elixir's Axon library?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, elixir

I'm trying to use the Axon library. I've been reading the documentation (https://hexdocs.pm/axon/Axon.Loop.html) and can't find how I can get an array of the history after the model is run.

I can see the state with code similar to

```
something = fn state ->
  IO.inspect(state, label: "state_is")
  {:continue, state}
end

Axon.Loop.trainer(model, loss, optimizer)
  |> Axon.Loop.handle_event(:epoch_completed, something)
  |> Axon.Loop.run(loop, train_data, %{}, epochs: epochs)
```

With Keras it's done like this:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=2)
loss_history = history.history["loss"]
```